# Answering Make line from QtCreator

Tags: compilation, linker, cmake, makefile, qt-creator

I am trying to import a cmake project that I build as a Qtcreator project. The CMakelist file I created automatically download some of the libraries needed. In the making process (`make`) the terminal asks:

```
replace \this\lib\archive\.DS_Store [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename: make[2]:...
```

The Qtcreator build is not showing me this line but it is waiting for me to answer. I know that since when I stop tre process, then it shows it in the issues prompt.

the answer for me can be always `all`: how set it as a default?

[edit] the code that produces that question is:

```
DOWNLOAD_COMMAND unzip -d ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/archive/somezip.zip
```

my workaround is to use `unzip -f -d`, but my question still remain open: how to interact with QtCreator?

Comment: can you share some code from the CMakeLists.txt where this question is produced?

Comment: thanks for your comment, the question was produced by an `unzip -d`, my workaround for now is to use `unzip -f -d`